# WPF Main menu for different views / viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'd like to create an app, containing the main menu (ribbonmenu) and different usercontrols, each assigned to an own ViewModel.

I was told to not implement classic events in code-behind but to use commands. So far, everything fine, commands for needed methods are implemented.
In my previous approach I "loaded" the `UserControl`, by assigning the corresponding ViewModel to a `ContentControl`, that loaded the `UserControl`, that was assigned to the ViewModel in `MainWindow.Resource`.

My last approach, simplified with a button instead of a menu:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="settingsViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:SettingsViewModel}">
        <views:SettingsView DataContext="{Binding SettingsVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="projectsViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ProjectViewModel}">
        <views:ProjectView DataContext="{Binding ProjectVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Load Settings" Height="20" Margin="20 20 20 0" Click="ShowSettings"/>
    <ContentControl Margin="5" Height="100" Content="{Binding}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

simplified code-behind:

```
    public SettingsViewModel settingsViewModel;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        settingsViewModel = new SettingsViewModel();
    }
    private void ShowSettings(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            DataContext = settingsViewModel;
    }
```

How can I load a `UserControl`, using ViewModel commands?

Comment: Where are your commands defined in this example...? In the `SettingsViewModel`? How do you bind to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use code-behind to handle view models. A View model should handle view models. Generally the same view model that implements the commands.

First create a main view model for the `MainWindow` as data source. This view model will also handle the switching between the views. It's recommended to let all page view models implement a common base type e.g. `IPage`.

Also you don't need any locator for this scenario. The views inside the `DataTemplate` will automatically have their `DataContext` set to the data type that maps to the `DataTemplate`. `SettingsView` will automatically have `SetingsViewModel` as the `DataContext`. If this would be the wrong context, then your model design is wrong.

**IPage.cs**

```
    interface IPage : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      string PageTitel { get; set; }
    }
```

**SettingsViewModel.cs**

```
    class SettingsViewModel : IPage
    {
      ...
    }
```

**ProjectViewModel.cs**

```
    class ProjectViewModel : IPage
    {
      ...
    }
```

**PageName.cs**

```
    public enum PageName
    {
      Undefined = 0, SettingsPage, ProjectPage
    }
```

**MainViewModel.cs**
 An implementation of `RelayCommand` can be found at
 *Microsoft Docs: Patterns - WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern - [Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic)*

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ICommand SelectPageCommand => new RelayCommand(SelectPage);

  public Dictionary<PageName, IPage> Pages { get; }

  private IPage selectedPage;   
  public IPage SelectedPage
  {
    get => this.selectedPage;
    set 
    { 
      this.selectedPage = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this.Pages = new Dictionary<PageName, IPage>
    {
      { PageName.SettingsPage, new SettingsViewModel() },
      { PageName.ProjectPage, new ProjectViewModel() }
    };

    this.SelectedPage = this.Pages.First().Value;
  }

  public void SelectPage(object param)
  {
    if (param is PageName pageName 
      && this.Pages.TryGetValue(pageName, out IPage selectedPage))
    {
      this.SelectedPage = selectedPage;
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="settingsViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:SettingsViewModel}">
      <views:SettingsView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="projectsViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ProjectViewModel}">
      <views:ProjectView />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>

    <!-- Content navigation -->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Button Content="Load Settings" 
              Command="{Binding SelectPageCommand}" 
              CommandParameter="{x:Static PageName.SettingsPage}" />
      <Button Content="Load Projects" 
              Command="{Binding SelectPageCommand}" 
              CommandParameter="{x:Static PageName.ProjectPage}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedPage}" />
  <StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Just a quick question, why does `SelectPage` taken an `object` and not a concrete `PageName`?

Comment: It actually does. To use commands you implement `ICommand` which defines a `ICommand.Execute(object)` method. This means by default the `CommandParameter` is of type òbject`. You the have to cast the parameter to its real type. `RelayCommand` wraps a reusable implementation of `ICommand`. It takes a delegate as constructor parameter which is internally invoked when the framework invokes `ICommand.Execute` e.g. when `Button` is clicked. The `RelayCommand` I used here is an example from Microsoft Docs, which is not generic.

Comment: If you follow the link in my answer you can copy the implementation and easily convert it to a generic `RelayCommand<T>` where `T` is the type of the `CommandParameter`.

Comment: Hi @BionicCode, thank you for your example. I think I understand what happens here but I don't get it work. Execution of RelayCommand is triggered and `this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));` is hit. I could not any reaction in the view and no error. The MainWindow shows the toString of the MainViewModel `WpfApp1.ViewModels.MainViewModel`so I think, I'm not too far from solution. How can I debug that? Oh and is it right, that with this approach every command ist nested in the MainViewModel?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like the logic itself is working. Only the `DataTemplate` is not rendered. Please make sure the templates are added to a `ResourceDictionary` within the scope of the `ContentControl` or `ContentPresenter`. Then make sure you set the `DataTemplate.DataType` property. You _must_  set it using the `x:Type`  markup e.g. `DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:SettingsViewModel}"`. Make sure you don't have any typos and that each `DataTemplate` maps to an existing data type/view model. Don't use the `x:Key` directive - very important. Let me know if this helped you to fix the issue.

Comment: Regarding the commands: all navigation commands should be defined inside the view model that handels the navigation (in your case `MainViewModel`). Of course every page or view can have its own commands that relate to the content and logic. E.g. a settings view model would implement its own _SaveCommand_.

Comment: I've read your comment again and stumbled across the info that you can only see the string representation of `MainViewModel`. This is wrong. In case the `DataTemplate` couldn't be resolved, you should see the string representation of a _page view model_ e.g. `ProjectViewModel` and not the `MainViewModel`. Make sure you have implemented the `MainViewModel` like in the example.

Comment: `MainViewModel` must be the `DataContext` of the `MainWindow` (or at least of the parent control that hosts the navigation buttons and the view host e.g. `ContentControl`). Your bindings may not resolve as you have accidentally bound the `ContentControl.Content` to the `MainViewModel`, which has no `DataTemplate` defined and therefore the `ContentControl` just renders the `MainViewModel.ToString` value. This may have happened due to a wrong `DataContext`.

Comment: If you still have troubles, please edit your question and post your current implementation. A shortened version of `MainViewModel` (navigation logic and properties) and the view including the templates and `DataContext` assignment. Then I could review your code.

Comment: By the way I can guarantee that the posted code/pattern is working. It must be a very small detail that you accidentally got wrong. I forgot: you can debug the issue using the _Live Property Explorer_ of Visual Studio. When in debug mode just select or navigate to the hosting `ContentControl` using the _Live Visual Tree_ and the inspect the control's `Content` and `DataContext` using the _Live Property Explorer_. You can also download and install the free WPF inspector _Snoop_. But the Visual Studio tools are good enough

Comment: [Snoop 2.11.0](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf/releases/download/2.11.0/Snoop.2.11.0.0.msi). ([GitHub Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf#where-can-i-download-snoophow-can-i-install-snoop)). It's a very good tool.

Comment: @BionicCode... Thank you so much for your help. I solved it in my productive project in a similar way you told. My menuitems are available, not depending of the `SelectedPage` so I decided to let the commands inside their detail-VMs and transfer the MainVM-object as parameter to the VMs, so I could change the `SelectedPage`out of the detail-VMs. Your approach was perfect! Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

The short version:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModel

      public MyViewModel()
      {
           View = new MyUserControlView();
           View.DataContext = this; // allow the view to bind to the viewModel.
      } 

      ....

      public UIElement View {
            get; private set;
      }
  }
```

And then in XAML:

```
 <ContentControl Content={Binding View} />
```

There are variations on this theme but that's the basic premise. e.g., if you have a ViewModel that can be bound to multiple views, or ViewModels that have lifetimes longer than their view, you can use a FrameViewModel class like this:

```
public class FrameViewModel : INotifyProperyChanged; {
      public FrameViewModel(IViewModel viewModel; )
      {
           ViewModel = viewModel;
           View = viewModel.CreateView();
           View.DataContext = ViewModel;
      }
      public IViewModel ViewModel { get; set;...}
      public UIElement View { get; set; }
}
```

And then bind THAT into the host XAML with a ContentControl binding to Frame.View.

A more pure approach is to the  use the `DataTemplateSelector` class to instantiate the User Control in a DataTemplate. This is probably the method that WPF designers had in mind for connecting View and ViewModel in WPF. But it ends up spreading the mapping of View and ViewModel across three separate files (the custom C# DataTemplateSelector implementation; widely-separated static resource declaration and ContentControl wrapper in the hosting `Window`/`Page`; and the DataTemplate resources themselves which end up in resource files eventually if you have anything but a trivial number of ViewModel/View bindings.

Purists would argue, I suppose, that there's something dirty about having a viewmodel create a view. But there's something far more dirty about code to make `DataTemplateSelector`s work spread across five files, and inevitable complications with databindings that ensue while trying to tunnel a binding through a `DataTemplate`.

Comment: This is a very bad solution as your are currently handling the views in the view model. This question is tagged MVVM, so don't recommend such a solution. It is also redundant, because when using _implicit_ (keyless) `DataTemplate`, the framework (or the way the `ContentPresenter` is implemented) automatically loads the proper view. A `DataTemplateSelector` is only needed when you have type ambiguities or defined _explicit_  data templates.. When every navigable page or control has its own view model, the mapping happens automatically (as mentioned before).

Comment: So you bind the `ContentControl.Content` or `ContentPresenter.Content` to a _view model_ and the internal `ContentPresenter` of a `ContentControl` will automatically traverse the visual tree to lookup an implicit `DataTemplate` with a matching `DataTemplate.DataType`. If found, the template (view) will be rendered.

Comment: Spreading resources accross multiple files is also not a problem. That's what merged resources or `MergedResourceDictionary` is for. The lookup is handled by the framework (following certain lookup rules).

Comment: @Robin as I already had a similar approach in my prudtive project, like BionicCode explained, I followed his example and got it run lately. Thanks for your help.